# How to programmatically add ion-buttons to the Ionic nav bar? (Ionic 2, Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to be able to add buttons to the navbar programmatically. This HTML code should be added to the page (inside the `<ion-navbar>`), by using a sort of template (in Angular 2) or by code (typescript).

```
<ion-buttons right (click)="doSth()">
    <button ion-button outline icon-only color="primary" #hduiBtn>
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

I found that `ng-include` does not work in Angular 2, and while there are work-arounds, they are too messy to use in the situation I need it for.

I know Alerts can be created programmatically in Typescript, however, what about adding buttons? If not via standard classes, is it possible to do it by using `@ViewChild()`? I tried different things (pipes, template includes via variables and more), but couldn't end up with anything working in a stable manner unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ngFor. You fill your buttons list (object with button properties like icon , color) in your class and use ngFor in your template.

`<ion-buttons right (click)="doSth()">
    <button *ngFor='let button of buttons' ion-button outline icon-only color="{{color}}" #hduiBtn>
        <ion-icon name="{{icon}}"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>`

Comment: That's a step in the good direction, but I should have mentioned that it's a requirement that the page template does not need a lot of modification. For example, it'd be better to have something like a variable or a template include (since it's for building a specific framework which should be easy to use -- I don't want developers using this framework to be required of having to add all that code themselves into the template).

Comment: Well basically, I'd need to find a way to add the code from the page's class, so I could put it in the superclass, hidden from the developer. The template should only contain a very small amount of code (like display of a variable or other). And the code I put in the question should be added into the <ion-navbar> tag of the template -- but not by writing, but by using a variable or similar. There isn't more code about this question, so I'm unsure what to post to plunker unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can add html dynamically to your template from your typescript code. But you can not add angular code dynamically. Because angular complie once and it can not complie your dynamic code. So use html and pure javascript instead. Here is the example:
In html: `<div id="parent"> </div>` 
In typescript:

```
    let parent = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById('parent');
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    let text = document.createTextNode("Click me");
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.setAttribute('id','button1');
    parent.appendChild(button);
    let button1 = <HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById('button1');
    button1.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      //your code here
      console.log("Button clicked");
    })
```